# Shared tooltips between bars and data not render successfully in D3 stack bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm adding a tooltip to my stacked bar chart using d3-tip.js. The expected out put of my tooltip should be when the mouse hoover to the specific stack of a bar, the tooltip will show the population of that specific stack. As shown below, each stack on each bar represent a gender, male or female. The number above the bar is the sum of the population of male and female. Now I want the tooltip display the individual population of each gender. However, there are 3 problem in my implementation:

1. The data seems not render successfully, as the graph shown below, the data dose not render successfully.
2. The second problem is the tooltip shared between bars. For example, as the graph shown below, when my mouse is over the "female" (pink) stack of the Unknown relationship, you can see both the stack of "Unknown" bar and "Other" bar are highlighted, so seems like they shared the same tooltip across bars.

[image]

3. The position of the tooltip display is incorrect. As shown below, when my mouse is on the Male (blue) stack of Other, the position of the tooltip is not on the "Other", instead, it is on the "unknown" bar.

[image]

Below is the code of adding tooltips:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
           .attr('class', "d3-tip")
           .style("color", "white")
           .style("background-color", "black")
           .style("padding", "6px")
           .style("border-radius", "4px")
           .style("font-size", "12px")
           .offset([-10, 0])
           .html(function(d) { return `<strong>${d3.format(',')(keys, d => z(d.key))}</strong> population`; });

       svg.call(tip);

       svg
         .selectAll('g.layer')
         .on('mouseover', function(d) {
         // show the tooltip on mouse over
         tip.show(d, this);
         // when the bar is mouse-overed, we slightly decrease opacity of the bar.
         d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.7);
         }) 
         .on('mouseout', function(d) { 
         // hide the tooltip on mouse out
         tip.hide();
         d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
       });
```

And here is the link of the live demo of my graph in Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6xB2Kzi46hWL37UjlgTs?p=preview

Comment: Just curious... is this a part of some course as I solved another issue with very similar issues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189153/how-do-i-know-which-bar-the-mouse-is-in-for-d3-stacked-bar?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know which bar the mouse is in for D3 stacked bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189153/how-do-i-know-which-bar-the-mouse-is-in-for-d3-stacked-bar)

Comment: @Coola Yes, you answer my question. This is not for a course. Another question you answered is the same one here, That is my friend's account and we work together to solve this problem.